# Выдает ошибку при запуске кода Kivy в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Ошибка:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Nurana\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-04_17.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Atom Projects\Rahim.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.button import Button
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\button.py", line 49, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.label import Label
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 286, in <module>
     from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel, DEFAULT_FONT
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\__init__.py", line 1006, in <module>
     Text = Label = core_select_lib('text', label_libs)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 103, in core_select_lib
     'identify potential causes\n{1}'.format(category.capitalize(), err))
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1425, in critical
     self._log(CRITICAL, msg, args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1514, in _log
     self.handle(record)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1524, in handle
     self.callHandlers(record)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1586, in callHandlers
     hdlr.handle(record)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 894, in handle
     self.emit(record)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 247, in emit
     self._write_message(message)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 218, in _write_message
     stream.write(fs % msg)
   File "C:\Users\Nurana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 250-251: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить kivy и установить как показанно здесь

[Установка kivy](https://riptutorial.com/ru/kivy)

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо за помощь.